# Person who repeatedly fails

Tags: vocabulary

I would like to describe a person who invests in the stock market, but repeatedly fails each time. Is there a proper English term to describe this kind of person?

Thanks.

Comment: A *loser*.....?

Comment: Either unlucky or incompetent.  Hard to guess which without observing his behavior.

Comment: _A hapless investor._

Comment: Poor? Seriously, s/he sounds like a gambler. Gamblers are known for their dogged persistence in chasing the big payoff by taking chances and tempting fate. Interestingly, from a psychological standpoint, they seem to thrive on the "juice" of the risk. Furthermore, the real thrill to them is losing, because they then get a chance to try again and again and again . . .. An outsider can see that the juice is slowly ruining the gambler's life, but the gambler is in such deep denial that only an intervention by loved ones will (they hope) get the person on the road to recovery. Don

Answer (score 2):

I'd describe  that person as an ***[incompetent](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/incompetent)*** (and unfortunate too):

> - a person not possessing the necessary ability, skill, etc to do or carry out a task; incapable

Other common terms are:

A ***[loser](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/loser):***

> - A person who is unable to be successful on a sustained basis:
>
>   - *His mother considers his friends to be a bunch of losers.*

A  ***[failure](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/failure):***

> - a person or thing that is unsuccessful or disappointing.

also , according to context, an ***[underdog](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/underdog):***

> - One that is expected to lose a contest or struggle, as in sports or politics.

The Free Dictionary

Answer (score 0):

Poor?

Seriously, s/he sounds like a degenerate gambler.

Gamblers are known for their dogged persistence in chasing the big payoff. They take chances; they tempt fate. Interestingly, from a psychological standpoint, they seem to thrive on the "juice" or "high" of the risk. Furthermore, the real thrill to them is losing, because they then get a chance to try again and again and again . . ..

An outsider can see the juice slowly ruining the gambler's life, but the gambler is in such deep denial that only an intervention by loved ones will (they hope) get the person on the road to recovery.

In summary, the stock market, by and large, is a crap shoot. There are no guaranteed winners and plenty of losers. Speculation need not be blind, but even the best speculator loses from time to time. That's why a diverse portfolio is one way of "hedging your bets"!